# I'm receiving text messages that my family didn't send

Tags: android, virus, sms

Lately I've been receiving text messages from family members that they did **not** send. All 4 family members and I are a part of the SMS group where we send and receive messages related to our family.
These texts don't actually have any content except they do have attachments,usually 1 or 2kb, which I *obviously* don't open. Does my phone have a virus or something I should be worried about?
The Kaspersky anti-virus I run isn't picking up anything.